Did Galois know about regular polyhedra?
Did Galois know about regular polyhedra when he made his work on algebraic solutions? When I searched it, I found that we can check whether there are algebraic solutions using the dodecahedron or the icosahedron. So I wondered whether Galois approached the problem of whether there are algebraic solutions using regular polyhedra. If this was not Galois' idea, who first thought of the connection between regular polyhedra and algebraic solutions?

Galois certainly would have known about regular polyhedra, as would any mathematics student then or now, but I'm pretty sure the type of stuff you're talking about came a few decades after Galois died. In any event, Galois wasn't around long enough to be widely read in mathematics, so whatever forerunner stuff along these lines that existed at his time was probably unknown to him. (continued)

Have you looked at The Historical Development of the Theory of Equations of the Fifth Degree, a chapter in (the English translation of) Felix Klein's Lectures on Icosahedron? I haven't read this, at least not anytime recently enough to remember, but this seemed an obvious place to look. (I say "obvious" because Klein's book is fairly well known, although probably rarely read at the present time.)

Considering that platonic solids are constructed in Euclid's Elements and Galois attended École Normale, he was aware of them. However, they played no role in his work, which was algebraically and analytically motivated, see English translation of his writings. The geometrization of Galois theory is indeed due to Klein. In particular, quintic's connection to icosahedron was established in Weitere Untersuchungen über des Ikosaeder (1877).

@Conifold Hello, I have a question. Unlike Abel, Galois said that if there is a regular icosahedron, for example, there is a rotation $\sigma$ on the line segment connecting the vertices of the icosahedron and the opposite vertices, and a rotation $\tau$ on the line segment connecting the centers of the triangles connecting the centers of the faces of the triangles of the icosahedron and the centers of the faces opposite to them. If the rotation opposite to $\sigma$ is $\sigma^{-1}$,

@Conifold Galois said that the crucial difference from Abel is that he observed that $\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma$ is invariant. To what does this correspond in an algebraic way?

Galois certainly knew about regular polytopes, but his preserved work does not mention them in connection with group theory or algebraic equations. Connection between the groups of regular polytopes and algebraic equations was made explicit by F. Klein in his Lectures on Icosahedron (1884).
